# Yii2 sendfile response

Tags: response, yii2, sendfile

I am new to `Yii2` and I would really appreciated if anyone could help me to solve the problem. I want to make a download link and I use

```
Yii::$app->response->sendFile($path, $name, ['inline' => false])->send();
```

in download function but it just read the content of the file and display straight in the page. What I want to do is when users click the download link, the download dialog will pop up or the file will be automatically downloaded, rather than display the content. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: This is probably not Yii2 related at all but due to the fact that your browser never received a mime type or doesn't recognise it. What type of content are you trying to send? Perhaps use firebug or the debugging tools of your browser to check if a mime type is being received

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same problem. It turned out that my link to download action was placed inside the `Pjax::begin() Pjax::end()` methods, so the content of the file was treated as update for the page.

My solution: add `data-pjax="0"` attribute to download link.

Comment: Nice Job. I didn't know that Pjax could disturb the Download.

Comment: Should be chosen as the real answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is use php header function:

```
public function actionDownload() {
    $file = $_GET["file"];
    $name = str_replace('files/prices/', '', $file);

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . urlencode($name) . "\"");
    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));

    ob_clean();
    flush();

    readfile($file);
}
```

And then call the link like this, with a timestamp:
http://page.com/download?file=files/prices/sillas.pdf&ts=1490725032

Answer (score -1):

Instead of :

```
 sendFile();
```

Try :

```
xSendFile()
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$mimetype='zip'; $mimetype='csv';
Yii::$app->response->sendFile($path.$name, $name, ['mimeType'=>$mimetype, 'inline'=>false]);    
return true;
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and offer more info in regard to how your code works and how it'll resolve the question.